# How to avoid getting the intent's extra to come back?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

### background

I have at least 2 activities on an app i've developing : a splash activity and a main activity. the splash activity calls the main activity.

on some cases (for now let's assume it's the first run only of the app) the splash activity adds a boolean extra (using intent.putExtra) to the intent to be true, and the main activity reads it using :

```
getIntent().getBooleanExtra(...,false);
```

### the problem

i only wish to see the flag as true when i open the main activity after the splash activity.

This is why i've tried to just call (in the onCreate, right after i get the flag) :

```
getIntent().removeExtra(...);
```

another approach (acccording to [**this website**](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.devel/144716)) would be:

```
final Intent newIntent = new Intent();
setIntent(newIntent);
```

and another approach could be:

```
getIntent().putExtra(..., false);
```

none of those work: for some reason, on some cases, the flag is still returned as true.

as an example, i can press the home button (when the main activity was in the foreground), and then i start a heavy app (like the cut-the-rope game or a benchmark app), and then return to the app using the launcher.

in this case (which doesn't always occur), the splash activity isn't shown, but instead the main activity is shown. it calls onCreate again, while the flag itself is still set to true .

### the question

why does it occur? how come the intent doesn't get reset?

is there a way to overcome this in an elegant way?

is it safe to just ignore the flag when the "savedInstanceState" is not null ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your VM is being torn down and re-started. I have observed on some devices that when the VM is re-created, instead of entering the launch activity, the last running activity is reconstructed from the saved state. It sounds like you are attempting to save state in the activity intent, so that is probably where your problems are coming from.

An important key to avoiding problems like this is to remember that the savedInstanceState bundle passed to onCreate is always null when the activity is being created *new*, in all other cases such as reconstructing after rotation or even when the VM has been torn down (as is likely your case) the savedInstance bundle passed to onCreate will be non-null.. my advice would be to use the intent to *initialize* your local state (the initial value of your flag) when the savedInstanceState is null, then never try to update your own intent, save your state in the savedInstance bundle..
E.G.

```
  class Someactivity extends Activity {
       private static final STATE_FLAG = "flagState";
       private boolean someFlag;

       protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          final Intent intent = getIntent();

          if(savedInstanceState==null) {
             // Brand new, set from intent
             someFlag = intent.getBooleanExtra(STATE_FLAG, false);
          } else {
             // Restored, set from saved instance
             someFlag = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_FLAG, false);
          }

       }

       protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) {
          // Save any updates to our activity state
          outState.putBoolean(STATE_FLAG, someFlag);
       }
    }
```

Comment: i don't understand why you access the savedInstanceState data , as it seems that you get the same flag value no matter what. anyway, in my case, where i don't want to have the flag value when the activity is re-constructed, is it ok to just ignore the flag in case the savedInstanceState!=null ?

Comment: The reason is that if you *change* the flag value in your code after looking at it for some reason (which sounds like what you are doing) the updated version will be passed in on reconstruction of the activity following rotation or vm teardown..

Comment: Oh, and actually it sounds like you could use savedInstanceState == null instead of the flag (true ONLY on the first time the activity is launched)..

Comment: now i'm more confused of what you are trying to say. what i wanted is to get the flag value ONLY after the main activity was really opened after the splash activity. the methods i've used were in order to prevent using it in all other cases (bot configuration changes and restoring of the activity). i asked about checking savedInstanceState==null since that seems like the correct case that i need to check.